# Mapping a string or numerical to a NxM binary matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, plot

I have a fun little problem.

I need to make a function that takes as input a string such as `"John Doe"` or `"New York 10001"`. There are a few requirements for the output.

1. Should be a `NxM` matrix, not necessarily square.
2. Should only be binary.
3. The input does **not** have to be reversible from the output.
4. When plotting it, the graphics has to retain a *visual resemblance* across sizes of the matrix.

Requirement 3 is soft in the sense that it's going to be difficult to retain a visual resemblance between a 2x2 matrix and a 100x100 matrix.

I have made some simple codes that fulfils requirements 1) and 2)

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def char_to_bin(string, h, l):
    
    _bin = bin(int.from_bytes(string.encode(), 'big'))[2:]
    
    print(len(_bin))
    
    _array = np.array(list(_bin)).astype('int')
    
    res = abs(h*l - len(_array))
    
    if (res & 1) == 1:
        r1, r2 = res//2, res//2 + 1
        
    if (res & 1) == 0:
        r1, r2 = res//2, res//2
    
    if len(_array) == h*l:
        
        return _array.reshape(h, l)
            
    if len(_array) < h*l:
        
        _array = np.pad(_array, (r1, r2), 'wrap')
                
        return _array.reshape(h, l)   
    
    if len(_array) > h*l:
        
        a1 = _array.copy()
        a2 = a1[r1:]
        a3 = a2[:-r2]
                
        return a3.reshape(h, l) 

London2020 = char_to_bin('London', 20, 20)
London1010 = char_to_bin('London 1010', 5, 5)

plt.imshow(London55)
plt.imshow(London2020)
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see requirements 3 is obviously lacking quite a bit from my current implementation. Anyone has any better ideas? Obviously something like a QR code (without the squares in the corners) would be useful, however a QR code also fails requirement 3).

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an operation on matrices called the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) that can be used to replicate the structure of one matrix at a larger scale using another as a pattern. You can use this to take 0/1 matrices and [replicate them at larger scales](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs224w/cs224w.1202/slides/02-gnp-smallworld.pdf#page=50):

[image: Example of the Kronecker product]

If you take a small (say, 4x4) random binary pattern and then multiply itself multiple times via the Kronecker product, you can get larger and more detailed images that all have the same self-similar structure. This would enable you to get images that work across multiple levels of scale.

The basic idea goes like this: given an m × n matrix, make an m<sup>2</sup> × n<sup>2</sup> matrix that you can think of as replacing each bit in the original m × n matrix with another copy of the original m × n matrix. Specifically, each 1 bit gets replaced by a copy of the original matrix, and each 0 bit gets replaced by an m × n matrix of zeros.

Comment: Using the Kronecker product is a fun idea! I had though of other product based fractal algorithms as well. My problem with this approach is that the pattern is "just" repeated across sub parts of the matrix which I find visually unappealing, as the "smallest" pattern just repeats on a larger scale - much like what I demonstrate above.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure that I completely understand your problem, but if I understand it, here is a suggestion of an algorithm:

- Input the string. If the length of the string is `n`, and each char gives you 8 bits, convert the input into a list of `8n` bits.
- Input `h` and `l`. Compute `k` such that `k*h*k*l` is approximately `8n`; *i.e.*, `k = sqrt(8n / (h * l))`
- Arrange your bits in a rectangle matrix of size kh * kl
- Use an image scaling algorithm to get a matrix of size h * l

Comment: For the string `London` (48 bits) calculating `k` yields ~`1.4`. Translating this to a size of a matrix yields a `7x7` matrix and broadcasting 48 binary numbers into a shape of 49 yields an error. This can be solved, however the result will look a lot like my attempt. Also, using a image scaling algorithm will (as expected) just increase or decrease the size of an image, not create a pattern with *visual resemblance* across scale.

Comment: "a pattern with visual resemblance across scale" is an extremely vague requirement, and I would argue that using an image scaling algorithm fulfills this requirement. If you can explain more precisely what you want, I'd happily come up with other ideas. One way is to include examples of images with "visual resemblance across scale" in your question.